# How to configure Multiple Mult-Headed GPU Cards?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, gpu

I have a late 2011 Alienware Aurora R4 with two video cards:

- **GeForce GTX 590** Driving three 27" HP2711 monitors
- **GeForce GT 520** Driving one 32" Sharp AQUOS

About a year ago I attempted to install *(dual boot)* Mint Cinnamon and everything seemed to go well until I got to the point of configuring the displays. I spent a few days working on and researching the issues, and finally gave up as the majority of my research indicated it simply wouldn't work without investing in a single video card with four heads *(like [a GTX 760](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-760/specifications)).*

I'm interested in taking another attempt at this, and my research indicates that it may be possible today; however, I can find no definitive answer nor any instructions on what the configuration steps ought to be.

My questions is then two fold.

1. Is it possible to Ubuntu to run all four monitors properly with these two cards?
2. If so, what is required to properly configure the system?

Comment: What has been the ultimate solution? not sure how to make it work in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234519/enabling-triple-head-setup-with-two-nvidia-gt730-in-ubuntu

Comment: I never found a solution that worked, I eventually purchased a new card with four heads to run my monitors.

Comment: Do you happen to have its model name at hand?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it's possible
2. You will need Xorg to configure your system.

> ```
> Section "Monitor"
>     Identifier "monitor1"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
> Identifier "monitor2"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>     Identifier "monitor3"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Monitor"
>     Identifier "monitor4"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier  "Card1"
>     Driver "radeon"
>     BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
>     Option "DRI" "off"
>     Screen 0
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier  "Card1_2"
>     Driver "radeon"
>     BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
>     Option "DRI" "off"
>     Screen 1
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>     Option "ZaphodHeads"   "DVI-0"
>     Identifier  "Card2"
>     Driver "radeon"
>     BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
>     Option "DRI" "off"
>     Screen 0
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>     Option "ZaphodHeads"   "VGA-0"
>     Identifier  "Card2_2"
>     Driver "radeon"
>     BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
>     Option "DRI" "off"
>     Screen 1
>     Option "Rotate" "left"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "left"
>     Device "Card1"
>     Monitor "monitor1"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "middle"
>     Device "Card1_2"
>     Monitor "monitor2"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "right"
>     Device "Card2"
>     Monitor "monitor3"
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>     Identifier "farright"
>     Device "Card2_2"
> Monitor "monitor4"
> EndSection
>
> Section "ServerFlags"
>     Option  "Xinerama"  "True"
>     Option  "AIGLX" "False"
> EndSection
>
> Section "ServerLayout"
>     Identifier "layout1"
>     Screen 0 "left" 0 0
>     Screen "middle" RightOf "left"
>     Screen "right" RightOf "middle"
>     Screen "farright" RightOf "right"
>     Option        "Xinerama" "On"
> EndSection
> ```

Hope this help.

Comment: And where should this magical configuration file be located?